# Auto Search list and Scrape table

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, beautifulsoup, openpyxl

I want to automate the search process on a website and scrape the table of individual players (I'm getting the players' names from an Excel sheet). I want to add that scraped information to an existing Excel sheet with the list of players. For each year that player has been in the league, the player's name needs to be in the first column. So far, I was able to grab the information from the existing Excel sheet, but I'm not sure how to automate the search process using that. I'm not sure if Selenium can help. The website is https://basketball.realgm.com/.

```
import openpyxl

path = r"C:\Users\Name\Desktop\NBAPlayers.xlsx"

workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)

sheet = workbook.active

rows = sheet.max_row
cols = sheet.max_column

print(rows)
print(cols)

for r in range(2, rows+1):
    for c in range(2,cols+1):
        print(sheet.cell(row=r,column=c).value, end=" ")

    print()
```

Comment: How do you search for the player. give us a steps or sample url.

Comment: Can we provide some players name which are searching on webpage?

Comment: Dominique Jones,
Joe Young,
Darius Adams,
Lester Hudson,
Marcus Denmon,
Courtney Fortson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you have got the names from excel sheet so I used a name `list` and using python `request` module and get the page text and then use `beautiful soup` to get table content and Then I have use `pandas` to get the info in `dataframe`.

**Code**:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
playernames=['Dominique Jones', 'Joe Young', 'Darius Adams', 'Lester Hudson', 'Marcus Denmon', 'Courtney Fortson']

for name in playernames:
  fname=name.split(" ")[0]
  lname=name.split(" ")[1]
  url="https://basketball.realgm.com/search?q={}+{}".format(fname,lname)
  print(url)
  r=requests.get(url)
  soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
  table=soup.select_one(".tablesaw ")
  dfs=pd.read_html(str(table))
  for df in dfs:
      print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
https://basketball.realgm.com/search?q=Dominique+Jones
            Player Pos   HT  ...  Draft Year          College               NBA
0  Dominique Jones   G  6-4  ...        2010    South Florida  Dallas Mavericks
1  Dominique Jones   G  6-2  ...        2009          Liberty                 -
2  Dominique Jones  PG  5-9  ...        2011  Fort Hays State                 -

[3 rows x 8 columns]
https://basketball.realgm.com/search?q=Joe+Young
      Player Pos   HT  ... Draft Year           College             NBA
0  Joe Young   F  6-6  ...       2007        Holy Cross               -
1  Joe Young   G  6-0  ...       2009          Canisius               -
2  Joe Young   G  6-2  ...       2015            Oregon  Indiana Pacers
3  Joe Young   G  6-2  ...       2009  Central Missouri               -

[4 rows x 8 columns]
https://basketball.realgm.com/search?q=Darius+Adams
         Player Pos   HT  ...  Draft Year              College  NBA
0  Darius Adams  PG  6-1  ...        2011         Indianapolis    -
1  Darius Adams   G  6-0  ...        2018  Coast Guard Academy    -

[2 rows x 8 columns]
https://basketball.realgm.com/search?q=Lester+Hudson
      Season       Team  GP  GS   MIN  ...   STL   BLK    PF   TOV    PTS
0  2009-10 *  All Teams  25   0   5.3  ...  0.32  0.12  0.48  0.56   2.32
1  2009-10 *        BOS  16   0   4.4  ...  0.19  0.12  0.44  0.56   1.38
2  2009-10 *        MEM   9   0   6.8  ...  0.56  0.11  0.56  0.56   4.00
3    2010-11        WAS  11   0   6.7  ...  0.36  0.09  0.91  0.64   1.64
4  2011-12 *  All Teams  16   0  20.9  ...  0.88  0.19  1.62  2.00  10.88
5  2011-12 *        CLE  13   0  24.2  ...  1.08  0.23  2.00  2.31  12.69
6  2011-12 *        MEM   3   0   6.5  ...  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.67   3.00
7    2014-15        LAC   5   0  11.1  ...  1.20  0.20  0.80  0.60   3.60
8     CAREER        NaN  57   0  10.4  ...  0.56  0.14  0.91  0.98   4.70

[9 rows x 23 columns]
https://basketball.realgm.com/search?q=Marcus+Denmon
    Season Team        Location  GP  GS  ...  STL  BLK    PF   TOV    PTS
0  2012-13  SAN       Las Vegas   5   0  ...  0.4  0.0  1.60  0.20   5.40
1  2013-14  SAN       Las Vegas   5   1  ...  0.8  0.0  2.20  1.20  10.80
2  2014-15  SAN       Las Vegas   6   2  ...  0.5  0.0  1.50  0.17   5.00
3  2015-16  SAN  Salt Lake City   2   0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.00  0.00   0.00
4   CAREER  NaN             NaN  18   3  ...  0.5  0.0  1.56  0.44   6.17

[5 rows x 24 columns]
https://basketball.realgm.com/search?q=Courtney+Fortson
      Season       Team  GP  GS   MIN   FGM  ...   AST  STL  BLK    PF   TOV   PTS
0  2011-12 *  All Teams  10   0   9.5  1.10  ...  1.00  0.3  0.0  0.50  1.00  3.50
1  2011-12 *        HOU   6   0   8.2  1.00  ...  0.83  0.5  0.0  0.33  0.83  3.00
2  2011-12 *        LAC   4   0  11.5  1.25  ...  1.25  0.0  0.0  0.75  1.25  4.25
3     CAREER        NaN  10   0   9.5  1.10  ...  1.00  0.3  0.0  0.50  1.00  3.50

[4 rows x 23 columns]
```

Comment: Is that you are looking after?

Comment: That helped a lot but I have another issue. Would you mind taking a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59864925/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-tbody

Comment: Sorry mate I am away now.I will come back later.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have url list with players and scrape the pages using beautiful soup.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://example.com').read())
```

Comment: So there is no way to pull the names from excel?

Comment: Do you want to get in from hyperlink or a casual link inside a cell of excel?

Comment: i think i'm just going to use the answer given above, but maybe you can help with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59866400/scraping-wrong-table/59866568?noredirect=1#comment105868666_59866568