# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tbody'

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to create an Excel sheet with players' stats, but when I try to scrape a particular table I keep getting

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tbody'.

In this case, I want the advanced stats table of the listed players on the Excel sheet. If advanced stats don't exist, leave the row empty next to the name.

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
playernames=['Dominique Jones', 'Joe Young', 'Darius Adams', 'Lester Hudson', 'Marcus Denmon', 'Courtney Fortson']

for name in playernames:
  fname=name.split(" ")[0]
  lname=name.split(" ")[1]
  url="https://basketball.realgm.com/search?q={}+{}".format(fname,lname)
  response = requests.get(url)

  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
  table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'tablesaw', 'data-table-saw-mode-exclude':'columntoggle'}).tbody
  print(table)  

  columns = ['Season', 'Team', 'League', 'GP', 'GS', 'TS%', 'eFG%', 'ORB%', 'DRB%', 'TRB%', 'AST%', 'TOV%', 'STL%', 'BLK%', 'USG%', 'Total S%', 'PPR', 'PPS', 'ORtg', 'DRtg', 'PER']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)


  trs = table.find_all('tr')
  for tr in trs:
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [td.text.replace('\n', '') for td in tds]
    df = df.append(pd.Series(row, index=columns), ignore_index=True)

df.to_csv('international players.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: It looks like there might be a case you haven't considered? Are you sure that `https://basketball.realgm.com/search?q=Dominique+Jones` is one of the URLs you want to scrape. If you look at the web page, it doesn't show the columns you're looking for. I think there's a case you haven't considered where if a search returns multiple players, it doesn't show their stats on that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think You have provided wrong attribute name.this should `data-tablesaw-mode-exclude` **Not** `data-table-saw-mode-exclude`

Change this

```
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'tablesaw', 'data-table-saw-mode-exclude':'columntoggle'}).tbody
```

To This

```
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'tablesaw', 'data-tablesaw-mode-exclude': 'columntoggle'}).find_next('tbody')
```

Comment: That worked but why am I getting ValueError: Length of passed values is 23, index implies 21? I counted multiple times and I think I have it down correct.

Comment: Sorry mate I left for the day.I will come back tomorrow.meanwhile try some research.

Answer (score 0):

In the line where you make the `soup.find(....` you are looking for the `data-table-saw-mode-exclude` attribute but it has to be `data-tablesaw-mode-exclude`.