# Scraping wrong table

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the advanced stats of players onto an excel sheet but the table it's scraping is the first one instead of the advanced stats table.

```
ValueError: Length of passed values is 23, index implies 21
```

If i try to use the id instead, i get an another error about tbody.

Also, I get an error about

```
lname=name.split(" ")[1]
IndexError: list index out of range.
```

I think that has to do with 'Nene' in the list. Is there a way to fix that?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
playernames=['Carlos Delfino',
'Yao Ming',
'Andris Biedrins',
'Nene']

for name in playernames:
  fname=name.split(" ")[0]
  lname=name.split(" ")[1]
  url="https://basketball.realgm.com/search?q={}+{}".format(fname,lname)
  response = requests.get(url)

  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
  table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'tablesaw', 'data-tablesaw-mode-exclude': 'columntoggle'}).find_next('tbody')
  print(table)  

  columns = ['Season', 'Team', 'League', 'GP', 'GS', 'TS%', 'eFG%', 'ORB%', 'DRB%', 'TRB%', 'AST%', 'TOV%', 'STL%', 'BLK%', 'USG%', 'Total S%', 'PPR', 'PPS', 'ORtg', 'DRtg', 'PER']
  df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

  trs = table.find_all('tr')
  for tr in trs:
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [td.text.replace('\n', '') for td in tds]
    df = df.append(pd.Series(row, index=columns), ignore_index=True)

df.to_csv('international players.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: You should include the complete error messages you get (also formatted). Also, it seems in order to reproduce your error there is no need of pandas. So, if anybody would like to help you, it is easier if you provide the minimal code which causes the problem, so the person which would like to help you does not have to install e.g. pandas.

Comment: As an aside, creating a DataFrame by appending is a bad idea, and rarely necessary. Is that `df.to_csv()` at the wrong indentation level?

Comment: I'm trying to refactor your code, what data are you looking to get from the site?

Comment: i'm trying to get the international Advanced Stats of each player and put them in an excel sheet with their names in the first column next each of their rows

Comment: @J.Doe You want to group all the players together, is that right?

Comment: for each season a player has, i want him to have his own row with his name in the first column for each row. so if the first player has 5 seasons, i want his seasons listed in the first 5 rows, then the next players seasons in the next rows. does that make sesnse?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206474/discussion-between-amc-and-j-doe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brazilians only use one name for soccer think Fred. If you want to use their moniker (Nene/Fred) then you need to implement exception handling for this, something like

```
try:
    lname=name.split(" ")[1]
except IndexError:
    lname=name
```

For your scraping issue, try using `find_all` as opposed to `find`, this will give you every data table on a given page and then you can pull the correct table out of the list

Change `table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'tablesaw', 'data-tablesaw-mode-exclude': 'columntoggle'}, {'id':'table-3554'})` to `find_all`

FYI also, the table ID's change every time you refresh the page so you can't use ID as a search mechanism.

Comment: the name issue seems to be fixed but i realized i forgot to change the "table = " line. i changed it back. the id should not be in there. however, i tried to use find_all and it didn't work for me

Comment: the error i get is ```AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?```

Comment: Find_all will return a list, `table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'tablesaw', 'data-tablesaw-mode-exclude': 'columntoggle'})[somenumber]` will let you figure out which table is the advanced stats table... and then you can call `.find_next('tbody')` on it

Comment: so table = (soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'tablesaw', 'data-tablesaw-mode-exclude': 'columntoggle'})[somenumber]).find_next('tbody') ? getting a keyerror. also do i just count the tables?

Comment: It's a without delving too deep into the mechanisms, yes..... you could also implement more nuanced logic to find only the advanced stats table.

Comment: i tried ```table = (soup.find_all('table', attrs={'class': 'tablesaw', 'data-tablesaw-mode-exclude': 'columntoggle'})[somenumber]).find_next('tbody')``` and got the error ```IndexError: list index out of range```

Comment: yea obviously it's a number associated with the table [18] i put in there but list index out of range

Comment: so it looks like the error is because for the first player the table is 18 but for the next player it is 11. how do i find a consistent identifier?